# Not able to fetch State using Geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps

Not able to fetch State using Geocoder. Tried lot of ways in stack but with no solution.Is it possible to get using Geocoder. I have also tried with `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.,88&sensor=true&key=` but it returns json but not directly State.For just getting state do I need to parse full json.Is there any simple solution

This is the mostly used method but  returns null

```
public void getAdressFromLatlng1(Double lat,Double lng) {

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Coordinates",lat+""+lng);
        if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()>0) {
            String state=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            Log.d("State",state);
        }
    }
```

Also tried this but also returns null:

```
private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(0)).append("\n");
                String cityName = "", stateName = "", countryName = "", zipCode = "";

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addresses.get(0).getLocality()) /*&& !isFromFilter*/) {
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_SETTINGS_CITY, addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_CITY, addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                }

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()) /*&& !isFromFilter*/) {
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_SETTING_STATE, addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_STATE, addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                }

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addresses.get(0).getCountryName()) /*&& !isFromFilter*/) {
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_SETTINGS_COUNTRY, addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_COUNTRY, addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                }

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode()) /*&& !isFromFilter*/)
                    prefs.setString(Prefs.PREFS_KEY_SETTING_ZIP, addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());

                /*strReturnedAddress.append(addresses.get(0).getLocality()).append("\n");//City
                strReturnedAddress.append(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()).append("\n");//State
                strReturnedAddress.append(addresses.get(0).getCountryName()).append("\n");//Country
                strReturnedAddress.append(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());//Zip Code

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }*/
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                Log.w("address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("address", "Canont get Address!");
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_get_address), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return strAdd;
    }
```